# Why can't I change the return type of overriden methods (other than covariant return type)?

Tags: java, jvm, overriding

PLEASE NOTE - I am asking WHY? It would be very useful if you could give an example where changing the return type actually breaks the code

why can't I change the return type of an overridden method (other than covariant return types).

```
class Parent{

   public void sayhello(){ ... };

}

class Child extends Parent{

    public String sayhello() { . . .}

}
```

Now if I run the following code:

```
class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       Parent p = new Child();
       p.sayHello(); 

        }
    }
```

Cam someone please confirm if the following steps are happening:

1. Compiler finds out the type of object 'p' which is Parent.
2. Compiler checks if method 'sayHello()' is present in Parent class.
3. During Runtime, JVM finds out that it is a Child object and calls child version of the method.
4. Child method is called.

Thanks.

Comment: You are overriding the **method**, not the **method signature**. Asking the same question multiple times will not help you and it annoys this community. :)

Comment: Last time someone marked it duplicate. That question is different to mine. I wanted to understand the reason behind why we cannot change it.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about the inside of the JVM, but I know that two methods with same name and arguments *but different return types* are considered different. Though it's not permitted by the compiler, it is allowed in bytecode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's use a simple example to explain why it doesn't make **any** sense to change the return type of an overridden method.

Suppose I have a `Car` object:

```
class Car {

    public String getModel() {
        return "Awesome Car";
    }
}
```

This `Car` class has a method `getModel()` that returns a `String`.

Now, you have another class that extends `Car` and overrides the `getModel()` method:

```
class DumbCar extends Car {
    @Override
    public Hamburger getModel() {
        return new Hamburger();
    }
}
```

Suddenly, you have a major problem. You create a `DumbCar` object and since you know that all `Car` objects can tell you their model, you try to **get** that model:

```
DumbCar myCar = new DumbCar();
System.out.println(myCar.getModel());
```

The output is `A juicy Big Mac!`

Does that make any sense to you? You cannot drive a Big Mac.

---

Java is a heavily *type-safe* language. When you write a statement asking to `getModel()`, you need to be absolutely, 100% positive, that the data you get back is what you were expecting. Java enforces that expectation.

Comment: And that's why it's forbidden *at compile time* because, in that case, the compiler wouldn't know *unambiguously which method* to call. It's allowed in bytecode though (and used by obfuscators) because after compilation, the method is determined.

Comment: so can I say that - the child class has a contract with the parent class that each overridden method will have the same return type as of parent's method? ( ...like the parent class guarantees that its child class will return parent's return type or more specific subclass).

Comment: @lynxx - Exactly. The idea of a "contract" is absolutely correct. Basically, the parent class is saying "You can't use my method unless you promise to offer the same type of result that I do."

Answer (score 1):

Java is a statically typed language.

This means that the compiler checks that all types make sense before the program is even run. So you will not get errors at runtime because some method or field is not "there".

In order for this to work if you have code that says

```
MyBean x = something.getMyBean();
```

it cannot be allowed for a subclass of what the compiler has determined the type of `something` to be to change the return type of `getMyBean()` to something other than `MyBean` (subclasses of `MyBean` are also allowed, this is called narrowing the return type -- but even that was not possible before Java 5).

Comment: so can I say that - the child class has a contract with the parent class that each overridden method will have the same return type as of parent's method? ( ...like the parent class guarantees that its child class will return parent's return type or more specific subclass)

Comment: Yes, that's it. If you override the method, all callers that only know about the parent interface must still be able to call your method (all parameter types and the return type and the checked exceptions have to be compatible).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is basically that such a thing would make the Java type system unsound, and since Java has a statically-typed system this cannot be allowed.

Suppose you had an `Expression` interface:

```
interface Expression {
    Integer evaluate();
}
```

And now you have an `Addition` implementation:

```
class Addition implements Expression {
   private Expression left;
   private Expression right;

   Addition(Expression left, Expression right) {
       this.left = left;
       this.right = right;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer evaluate() {
     return left.evaluate() + right.evaluate();
   }
}
```

This works as long as expressions evaluate to Integers, e.g.

```
class Constant implements Expression {
   private Integer value;

   Constant(Integer value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   @Override
   public Integer evaluate() {
       return this.value;
   }
}
```

Which allows us to do things like:

```
Expression left = new Constant(1);
Expression right = new Constant(2);
Expression addition = new Addition(left, right);
Integer result = addition.evaluate();
```

What would happen now if you had an expression that instead of evaluating to an `Integer` evaluated to something else that is not an expression, like a `Cat` or a `Dog`?

It would immediately break the soundness of every other expression you had written in the past like that of the last example or the obvious assumptions we made in the `Addition.evaluate` method where we assumed that `left` and `right` expressions returned `Integer` not `Cats` or `Dogs`.